# Understanding Twitter Premium API Sandbox in python

Tags: python, twitter, twitterapi-python

I have already Twitter Standard API (I got the approved recently and did not use Twitter  API yet ) because I need to collect historical tweets.
So I have to upgrade to Premium API but should I choose API sandbox to test my code before paid and upgrade the premium API full archive? I am afraid to lose some tweets and reduce the requests.
I am a little confusing for understanding some operators
results_per_call=100 .. max_results=100 .. what are they meaning?
Can I choose any numbers to get more tweets?
How many requests can I use per day?
I find code in python that I will use it to collect ? is it correct? I am a beginner  in python
where can I find the JSON file on my computer.? and how convert this file to .cvs?

```
!pip install searchtweets
!pip install yaml
import yaml
config = dict(
search_tweets_api = dict(
    account_type = 'premium',
    endpoint = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/tweets/search/fullarchive/YOUR_LABEL.json',
    consumer_key = 'YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY',
    consumer_secret = 'YOUR_CONSUMER_SECRET'
))
with open('twitter_keys_fullarchive.yaml', 'w') as config_file:
yaml.dump(config, config_file, default_flow_style=False)
from searchtweets import load_credentials
premium_search_args = load_credentials("twitter_keys_fullarchive.yaml",
                                   yaml_key="search_tweets_api",
                                   env_overwrite=False)
print(premium_search_args)
from searchtweets import gen_rule_payload 
query = "(#COVID19 OR  # Corona_virus) (pandemic OR corona OR  infected OR vaccine)" rule = gen_rule_payload(query, results_per_call=100, from_date="2020-01-01", to_date="2020-01-30")`         from searchtweets import ResultStream
rs = ResultStream(rule_payload=rule,
              max_results=100,
              **premium_search_args) print(rs)
mport json
with open('twitter_premium_api_demo.jsonl', 'a', encoding='utf-8') as f:
n = 0
for tweet in rs.stream():
    n += 1
    if n % 10 == 0:
        print('{0}: {1}'.format(str(n), tweet['created_at']))
    json.dump(tweet, f)
    f.write('\n') print('done')
```

Very thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Once I had the same task that collect twitter data using different conditions,After lot of searching and tests,I had to create completely separate python twitter client API for my task.This is what I know regarding the API (documentation is little bit confusing)

Twitter API has 3 versions for search and download data.

- Standard(free version with limitations)
- Premium (paid version with some extended features)
- Enterprise ( paid version with customize options for large scale operations)

**Standard API**

- Free to use with correct authentication
- Only return past 7 days data
- Can use Standard search operators
- You can send limited number of requests within given time period(ex 180 requests in 15min window for user auth and 450 requests in 15 min window for app auth)
- one request return  100 data objects (100 tweets)

**Premium API**

Preimum APi includes 2 versions.

1. 30-day Endpoint - Provide tweets posted within last 30 days
2. Full Archive endpoints - Provides tweets from starting from 2006

these 2 versions share the same endpoints and only difference is timeframe you can search.

- Premium package returns maximum 500 data objects per request,Still you can limit the return count according to your use case.
- Select requests per month by subscription (example 50 requests,250 requests (per month))

Answering your questions:

**results_per_call=100** means how many tweet objects return by the API by default and **max_results=100** is how many objects you need.

*should I choose API sandbox to test my code before paid and upgrade the premium API full archive?*

yes you can test basic logic and some search queries and check return object using free service.But if you need to search date difference more than 7days, or premium operators you have to use premium API.

these are some useful links

https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/overview

operators

https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/guides/standard-operators
https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/guides/premium-operators

API

https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/api-reference/premium-search
https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/api-reference/get-search-tweets

There are more hidden information in documentation please add more if you find anything useful.